# Saving data frame of user input

Tags: r, shiny

**Note: Please feel free to criticize the code I have written as I'm learning, what I did wrong, how I can improve etc.**

I am learning R and shiny and would like to implement a calculation using the users input, however I am having difficulty storing the user input into a data frame for me to access to run a calculation later.

My idea is to get the user to define a probability distribution for his or her selected variables from the iris dataset. Once he defines them I want to store those defined variables into a data frame so that I can run a calculation such as a Monte Carlo etc. using the users defined data frame later on (so I would need to call upon that as a data frame).

I have tried to make the code as simple as possible below :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
    wellPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId= "invar", label= "Select Variable", 
                     choices= names(iris), 
                     selected= names(iris)[1],
                     multiple=T),
  uiOutput("moC"))),


  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("tab")
  )
))
server <- function(input, output) {

  sorted <-  reactive({
    data <- iris[ ,c(input$invar)]

    data})

  output$moC <- renderUI({
    numvar<- length(input$invar)
    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
    tagList(
      selectInput("inv",paste0("Please Select Probability Distribution of ", input$invar[i]),
                  choices = c("Normal","Uniform")),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Normal'",
                       textInput("invarpdfmean","Please Select Input Variable Mean:",0.25),
                       textInput("invarpdfsd","Please Select Input Variable Standard Deviation", 0.02)),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Uniform'",
                       textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                       textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value", 0.3))


    )})})
}
```

**EDIT: Updated code as per comments. Thanks**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           wellPanel(
             selectizeInput(inputId= "invar", label= "Select Variable", 
                            choices= names(iris), 
                            selected= names(iris)[1],
                            multiple=TRUE),
             uiOutput("moC"))),


    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("tab")
    )
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {

  sorted <-  reactive({
              iris[input$invar]
              })

  output$moC <- renderUI({
    numvar<- length(input$invar)
    lapply(1:numvar, function(i) {
      tagList(
        selectInput("inv",paste0("Please Select Probability Distribution of ", input$invar[i]),
                    choices = c("Normal","Uniform")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Normal'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmean","Please Select Input Variable Mean:",0.25),
                         textInput("invarpdfsd","Please Select Input Variable Standard Deviation", 0.02)),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.inv=='Uniform'",
                         textInput("invarpdfmin","Please Select Minimum Input Variable Value:",0.18),
                         textInput("invarpdfmax","Please Select Maximum Input Variable Value", 0.3))


      )})})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT 2:**
Seems I wasn't clear apologize:
The desired output is a histogram of a linear model of the users selected variables with the data coming from the users defined variables. So if he selects `Sepal.Length` and `Petal.Length` and defines them with a uniform or normal distribution I want to run a Monte Carlo on the linear model using a data frame created from the users input.

So later on i want to run a code that looks something like this:

```
n<-1000
Lm <- Sepal.Length + Petal.Length
    for (n in 1:n) {
      H=predict(LM,MCtab)
    }
```

where MCtab would be a data frame which is created by the user using the variables he or she selects. This is what I have not been able to figure out how to do.

Comment: About the code: 1. never use `T` instead of `TRUE`, 2. prefer `iris[input$invar]` rather than `iris[, c(input$invar)]`, 3. you don't need to put the result in `data` and then return `data`, you just need to return the result.
About the App: what is `tab`?

Comment: If you want to use `tab`, use 
```sorted <- reactive(iris[input$invar])
    output$tab <- renderTable(sorted())```

Comment: @F.Privé thanks for the comments on the code.`tab` was the id for a table output that would let the user see a sample of the data which was defined by the user (like 3-4 rows). There is to be another output `plotOutput`  that would generate a histogram of the result from the calculation which i haven't added yet. Any ideas on how I can save the user defined variables in a data frame?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Dont you want to select some of the variables of the data frame like this `iris[input$invar]`?

Comment: @F.Privé I want to save the users selected variables into a data frame which can be accessed later on in a calculation. So for example you select `Sepal.Length` and `Petal.Length` and define them with a probability distribution. I want that to be saved in a data frame which I can later access in order to calculate a formula

Comment: Can you provide a small desired output?

Comment: @F.Privé I have edited to hopefully be more clearer

Answer (score 0):

For `MCtab` (which is just a subset of your dataset based on user selected inputs), you can use `MCtab <- iris[ , input$invar]`. Note the comma there. Also, you should check if `input$invar` is empty in case user has deleted all the choices.